# Exception with Rest Sharp Assembly

Tags: c#, .net, restsharp

I'm encountering the following error message:

```
Error Message : threw exception: 
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'RestSharp, Version=106.6.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=598062e77f915f75' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

Comment: you can reinstal NugetPackage, edit manifest , load dll in code [Assembly.LoadFrom()];(not recommend)....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Nuget Package Manager and Change the version of Rest Sharp and install it. The issue will be resolved.